# Is there a way of getting a raw psql query of an sequelize method?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, backend

For example, I have the following case:

```
const user = await User.findByPk(1);
```

But I need to know the psql query to get the exact result, how can I get that query from its sequelize form of getting the result, in this case it would be something like "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
await User.findByPk(1, {logging: console.log});
```

source: [https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-findByPk](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-findByPk)